# wrong timezone in java

Tags: java, datetime, calendar, timezone

i have a method in which i am trying to fetch system's local time zone, but i am always get "Coordinated Universal Time" as a time zone where i am expecting it to be "India Standard Time"

code is as below

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
              
 //get local TimeZone by
TimeZone timezone = c.getTimeZone();
              
System.out.println("Local TimeZone is : " + timezone.getDisplayName());
```

Please let me know how to fetch user's system timezone dynamically Thanks!

Comment: `ZoneId.systemDefault()` for example... (that's from `java.time`).

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use `java.time` (recommended nowadays anyway and definitely to be preferred over `java.util`):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // first, define a locale for your output
    Locale locale = Locale.ENGLISH; // you can use your system default here, too
    // then get the zone id of the system
    ZoneId sysZoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault();
    // and use one of its names (full, narrow, short) in the defined language
    String sysZoneFullName = sysZoneId.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, locale);
    String sysZoneShortName = sysZoneId.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, locale);
    String sysZoneNarrowName = sysZoneId.getDisplayName(TextStyle.NARROW, locale);
    // get the offset from UTC the zone currently has
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now(sysZoneId);
    ZoneOffset sysOffset = odt.getOffset();
    // then prepare some output (could be done in a better way ;-) )
    int offsetInSeconds = sysOffset.getTotalSeconds();
    char direction = (offsetInSeconds < 0) ? '-' : '+';
    // then output each zone representation (full, narrow, short) and the offset from UTC
    System.out.printf("%s / %s / %s has an offset of %s%d hours from UTC",
            sysZoneFullName, sysZoneNarrowName, sysZoneShortName, 
            direction, offsetInSeconds / 3600);
```

On my system (located in Germany), this outputs

```
Central European Time / Europe/Berlin / CET has an offset of +2 hours from UTC
```

Check out the different options of getting the name of a `ZoneId` for your code. There are `STANDALONE` versions for each name representation, too. I hope you find the one you need.

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately, `IST` is none of the representations provided by `ZoneId`. Instead, you will get `IT` or `India Time` if your `systemDefault()` is `"Asia/Kolkata"`. I have tried to define that zone and print its representations:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Locale locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
    ZoneId ist = ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata");
    System.out.println(ist.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, locale));
    System.out.println(ist.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE, locale));
    System.out.println(ist.getDisplayName(TextStyle.NARROW, locale));
    System.out.println(ist.getDisplayName(TextStyle.NARROW_STANDALONE, locale));
    System.out.println(ist.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, locale));
    System.out.println(ist.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT_STANDALONE, locale));
}
```

and it outputs

```
India Time
India Time
Asia/Kolkata
IT
IT
IT
```

Better than nothing, you can use the output as a condition for printing what you need.

Answer (score 2):

This will give the local time zone:

```
import java.time.ZoneId

ZoneId zone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get device time zone dynamically by below code

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
              
TimeZone timezone = c.getTimeZone();

TimeZone.setDefault(null);

System.out.println("Local TimeZone is : " + timezone.getDisplayName());
```

Comment: It doesn’t work dynamically for me. It keeps displaying the OS time zone that was set the first time even when the snippet is run again after I have changed the OS time zone.